# How can I embed fonts in a kindle ebook (azw3/kf8)

Tags: kindle, fonts, kindle-paperwhite, embedding

I want to read a Microsoft Word document (`.docx` format) on my Kindle Paperwhite, with its original two fonts (every third paragraph has a different font from the rest of the document). How do I do that?

Comment: It's not clear whether you are producing this ebook for your personal use (or for friends). Or are you actually trying to publish this book? If the latter, you probably should use Sigil or Calibre to make these adjustments.

Comment: I wrote "on **my** kindle". but i would be interested in using Sigil or Calibre if you (or someone else) explains how.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just speculating wildly here, but the first thing you need to do is to specify 2 fonts which you know for sure are supported on the Paperwhite.

Kindle Personal Documents Service does some strange things. I'm not sure if it even reads font information from MS Word. It certainly will **not** embed fonts automatically from MS Word.

However, if it is able to read and convert font(s) info from MS word, Here's a list of Kindle fonts you can choose from (which may or may not be out of date). http://www.paulsalvette.com/2012/06/embedding-fonts-in-kindle-ebooks.html

You can differentiate texts in other ways than fonts. For example, you can put it in *italics* or make the font size smaller. Generally it is frowned upon to use more than one font except on the heading.